# Tensorflow: batch not shaping correctly for labels

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using an `LSTMBlockFusedCell` for a network I'm working on. 
When fed a single input of size [6, 3169] and an output of [-1, 3169] (casts to input size), it operates properly and predicts. The problem comes when I try and batch those same inputs. With a batch of 100, the input reshapes fine, but the output broadcasts into [600, 3169]. I have tried setting the placeholder specs exactly to the specified input length, but the same error happened. I'm pretty confident that my data is in the correct shape. I run the batch generator and print the output sizes afterward.

Here's my network:

```
def rnn(x, weight, bias, n_input, vocab):
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, n_input, vocab])
    rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockFusedCell(n_hidden)
    outputs, states = rnn_cell(x, dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weight['output']) + bias['output']
```

my batch generator:

```
def new_data(dat, dic, n_steps, batch_size=100):
    x = np.zeros(shape=(batch_size, n_steps, len(dic)))
    y = np.zeros(shape=(batch_size, n_steps, len(dic)))
    j = 0
    x_dat = np.zeros(shape=(n_steps, len(dic)))
    for sen in dat:
        if len(sen) - 1 > n_steps:
            for i, word in enumerate(sen[0:n_steps]):
                x_dat[i] = one_hot(word, dic)
            y_dat = one_hot(sen[n_steps], dic)
            x[j % batch_size] = x_dat
            y[j % batch_size] = y_dat
            if j % batch_size == 0:
                yield x,y
                x = np.zeros(shape=(batch_size, n_steps, len(dic)))
                y = np.zeros(shape=(batch_size, n_steps, len(dic)))
            j += 1
```

and my setup:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
weights = {
    "output" : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, vocab_size]),name="weight_output")
}

bias = {
    "output" : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([vocab_size]), name="bias_output")
}
pred = rnn(X, weights, bias, n_input, vocab)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=pred, labels=Y))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    step = 0
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for x,y in new_data(dat, dic, n_steps):

            _ , c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: x ,Y: y})
```

Comment: where is the new_data function?